# graphql-js separate field definition from types

Tags: typescript, types, schema, definition, graphql-js

I got a question regarding graphql-js schema definition. I have following case, three types with identical fields in two types:

```
const aType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'aType',
  description: 'A type',
  fields: () => ({
    fieldA: {
      type: baseType,
      description:
        'The location of the order.',
      resolve: (root, { }) => "dummy resolve"
    }
  })
});

const bType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'bType',
  description: 'B type',
  fields: () => ({
    fieldA: {
      type: baseType,
      description:
        'The location of the order.',
      resolve: (root, { }) => "dummy resolve"
    }
  })
});

const baseType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'baseType',
  description: 'Base type',
  fields: () => ({
    dummy: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (root, { }) => "Hi"
    }
  })
});
```

Is it possible to define the identical field in aType and bType and then use the definition in the types?

Like so:

```
const fieldDefinition = {
      type: baseType,
      description:
        'The location of the order.',
      resolve: (root, { }) => "dummy resolve"
    }

const aType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'aType',
  description: 'A type',
  fields: () => ({
    fieldA: fieldDefinition
  })
});

const bType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'bType',
  description: 'B type',
  fields: () => ({
    fieldA: fieldDefinition
  })
});
```

I think it should be possible but I have issues with the typescript type that I would have to assign the fieldDefinition. 
An interface is not an option as the overlap between the objects is too small.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: I would think you wouldn't have to assign a type to it at all. As long as the shape is congruent, I would think it would just work?

Comment: It complains about the 'root' argument in the method declaration. It seems ok if I don't explicitly assign a type to fieldDefinition. It works if I give root the any type, but I don't think this is the correct way to do this.